# Java/JNLP: substitute user.home from argument list

Tags: java, properties, persistence, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a JNLP in which I provide some arguments to the main application.

I'd like to give a subdirectory of the user's home directory as an argument, in a portable (at least Windows/Linux) way.

I've tried to have a look at ${user.home}, but I don't really know if the JNLP will perform the substitution or not.

**EDIT**

To make it clear: I don't need a way to store or find some properties on the client machine. I need a way to pass an argument through a JNLP that include the user's home directory. This should obviously work on Windows and Linux platforms at least. To achieve this goal, I just want to read the system property "user.home" that is set up by the JVM. However, I think that Java Web Start could perform some substitution on the client.

It is true that the needed argument could be relative to the user's home directory, and my application could just load the system property. However, there are some use case when I don't want that behavior.

I was just trying a way to specify, in a platform independent way, the user's home directory…

Comment: Why do you need the substitution to be in the JNLP file itself. Just use `System.getProperty("user.home")` in your code, or even `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"myAppDir")`

Comment: Because it's an argument: this can be an arbitrary value, pointing to an existing directory. But here, inside the JNLP, I want it to be the user directory, whatever the final machine is.

Comment: The question still stands, why does it need to be an argument? As far as I know, the JNLP file is static and comes from a web-server as is. It should not need to add arguments other than general VM arguments. If you need to load other properties I would recommend using a properties file at a specific location with defaults for when the file does not exist (the application can dynamically create the properties file the first time it runs if need be).

Comment: Indeed. But this application can be run as a standalone, and for some location, I use a JNLP to ease the deployment. And depending on the location, this parameter can be different (there is multiple JNLP if you prefer this phrasing). Maybe the solution isn't in the argument list however…

Comment: When the initial argument is not implying `user.home`, where does the value come from?  Does the user specify it in a text field?  Are they offered a file chooser of some type? ..  Like @RudolphEst, I am having trouble understanding the problem.  BTW - look at the [`PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps) of the JNLP API.  The `PersistenceService` can be used to store the path to the properties, or better still, the properties themselves!

Comment: @AndrewThompson - `PersistenceService` only allows local caching of remote data, not local caching of local data, and is primarily intended for sharing data between different applications served from the same URL base. If you look at the methods for the service, you can only access URLs that have the same code base as the running application.

Comment: @RudolphEst *"`PersistenceService` only allows local caching of remote data,.."*  Did you try the demo.?  Successfully storing/restoring the *"notes the user types in, as well as .. the application's location, size, and PLAF."*  suggests otherwise.  If you have a problem, let me know.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Nope, I didn't even know there was a demo!! I just read the documentation which states... _"Data stored using this mechanism is intended to be a local copy of data stored on a remote server."_ I'll really want to look at that demo. Post a link please!

Comment: @RudolphEst  The link to the demo. is in my 1st comment! But direct link is, http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't see that link there. I think the JavaDoc is very misleading here, thanks for clarifying. (And the demo site is now bookmarked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, but I can't store properties on user directories. I just want the parameter lists to be portable, so that the user home directory is always found.

My solution is not perfect, it simply follows Apache's Ant way: replace occurrences of ${myvariable} with the corresponding value from the system properties.

Here's the code:

```
public class PropertySubstitutor {
    private static final Pattern VARIABLE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");

    public static String substitute(String source) {
        Matcher matcher = VARIABLE_PATTERN.matcher(source);
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(source.length());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, properties.getProperty(matcher.group(1), ""));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffer);
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private PropertySubstitutor() {}
}
```

This helper could be changed to use a user-defined properties object.

I use the slow regexp engine, cause I only need at application startup to parse two or arguments.

Comment: Java *always* finds the user home directory ... I think I still do not understand why you need to pass a parameter into a JNLP application in the first place. But your solution definitely would work if you had to pass '${some.param}' parameters to the JNLP.

Answer (score 1):

The only values that are automatically substituted by the web server in jnlp files are:

- $$codebase- The URL of the request except for the name of the JNLP file
- $$name   The name of the JNLP file
- $$context    The base URL of the web application
- $$site   The web server address
- $$hostname   The name of the server

These substitutions only happen if using the JNLPDownloadServlet in a servlet container.

The host cannot possibly know the value of the user home parameter when it downloads the JNLP file.

If you are deploying a JNLP that can be run as standalone, and you need to load arguments to the application I would recommend using a properties file at a specific location with defaults for when the file does not exist (the application can dynamically create the properties file the first time it runs or you could use an installer to do so).

Here is a detailed example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException{
         new Main();
    }

    private static Properties instance;

    public static Properties getProperties(){
        return instance;
    }

    private static Properties defaultProperties(){
        // implement default properties here
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("myApp.property1","someDefaultValue");
        return props;
    }

    public static void createDefaultPropsFile(File propsFile,Properties props) throws IOException {
        propsFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();            
        props.store(new FileWriter(propsFile),"My App Properties");
    }


    private Main() throws IOException{
         File appDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "myApp");
         // find property file
         File propsFile = new File(appDir, "settings.properties");
         Properties appProperties = new Properties(defaultProperties());
         if(!propsFile.exists()){
             createDefaultPropsFile(propsFile,appProperties);
         } else {
             appProperties.load(new FileReader(propsFile));
         }
         // this should really be done using a singleton or something similar
         instance = appProperties; 
         System.out.println("Property"+getProperties().getProperty("myApp.property1"));        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your redirect the desktop - java 7 and below seems set the user.home incorrectly.  doesn't line up with %userprofile% for example.